# Using varImp returns Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I'm trying to rank the features by importance using varImp function from the caret package. This is what i have:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", savePred=T)
mod <- train(Group~., data=metrics, method = "svmLinear", trControl = ctrl)
importance <- varImp(mod, scale=FALSE)
```

But the varImp function is giving me this error in Traceback:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
5.
FUN(newX[, i], ...)
4.
apply(x, 2, testFunc, y = y)
3.
filterVarImp(x_dat, y_dat, nonpara = nonpara, ...)
2.
varImp.train(mod, scale = FALSE)
1.
varImp(mod, scale = FALSE)
```

I thought I did everything just as the documentation did. I'm new to R and caret so this is really confusing me. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks for the recommendations for the question!  For the dataset, I think I'm not allowed to post it anywhere so I manually generated a smaller matrix that still reproduces the error described above.

```
    Group   f1      f2      f3       f4      f5
    0      5377.8   3506.9  1999.3   1659.9  448.7
    0      7963.4   4016    931.2    970     468
    0      5175.2   2449.8  802      1191.7  110.2
    0      6542     2198    938.8    965.5   115.1
    1      5641.2   3936.1  1639.5   1206    520.7
    1      8136.8   3527.7  1931     1765.1  582.4
    1      7195.5   2496.2  1650.8   1387    406.3
```

and I've used

```
metrics$Group <- as.factor(metrics$Group)
```

to set the Group column as categorical variables.

Comment: Please read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post how you arrived at your data set and some sample data.

Comment: Where can we find the data `metrics`?

Comment: I copied your code verbatim and I got no error (with caret version 6.0.80 and R 3.4.4). Thus either your error is elsewhere or you need to upgrade the package, likely.